Ошибка при импорте css в react приложение. У меня есть модуль, но мне нужен объект
В тестах приложения react с использованием typescript произошла ошибка.
Через несколько часов я понял, что ошибка заключается в способе импорта стилей.
Я провел несколько часов в чате gpt, но это не сильно помогло.
Когда я импортирую классы, подобные этому:
import * as cls from './Button.module.scss';
concole.log(cls) возвращает Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toString Tag): 'Module'}
В приложении нет ошибок, но есть ошибка в тесте (jest), связанная с классами.
Когда я использую:
import cls from './Button.module.scss';
Выскакивает ошибка в приложении:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Button')
    at Button (http://localhost:3000/main.28f6bcc41182abdc5bde.js:5916:153)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/main.28f6bcc41182abdc5bde.js:23669:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/main.28f6bcc41182abdc5bde.js:28281:13)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/main.28f6bcc41182abdc5bde.js:29804:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/main.28f6bcc41182abdc5bde.js:12347:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/main.28f6bcc41182abdc5bde.js:12396:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/main.28f6bcc41182abdc5bde.js:12460:31)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/main.28f6bcc41182abdc5bde.js:35668:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/main.28f6bcc41182abdc5bde.js:34774:12)
    at workLoopConcurrent (http://localhost:3000/main.28f6bcc41182abdc5bde.js:34760:5)

console.log(cls) возвращает Object, но при таком импорте в тесте ошибок нет.
webpack.config.js:
const cssLoader = {
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [
        // Creates style nodes from JS strings
        isDev ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
                modules: {
                    auto: (resPath: string) => Boolean(resPath.includes('.module.')),
                    localIdentName: isDev
                        ? '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:8]'
                        : '[hash:base64:8]'
                }
            }
        },
        "sass-loader",
    ],
}

Я не вносил никаких изменений в этот файл.
global.d.ts:
declare module '*.scss' { 
    interface IClassNames {
        [className: string]: string
    }
    const classNames: IClassNames;
    export = classNames;
}

Здесь я попытался заменить интерфейс на type, но на самом деле сам дизайн как был, так и остался.
jest.config.ts:
moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(s?css)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
},

Здесь я тоже использовал разные варианты указания расширений файлов, хотя в этих изменениях нет никакого смысла
babel.config.json:
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        [
            "@babel/preset-react",
            {
                "runtime": "automatic",
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "i18next-extract"
    ]
}

Babel не трогал особо.
Дополняю вопрос
Button.tsx:
import { classNames } from 'shared/lib/classNames/classNames';
import cls from './Button.module.scss';
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes, FC } from 'react';

export enum ThemeButton {
    CLEAR = 'clear',
    PRIMARY = 'primary'
}

interface ButtonProps extends ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
    className?: string;
    theme?: ThemeButton;
}

export const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = (props) => {
    const {
        className,
        children,
        theme,
        ...otherProps
    } = props;

    return (
        <button
            type='button'
            className={classNames(cls.Button, {}, [className, cls[theme]])}
            {...otherProps}
        >
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}

Дополняю вопрос 2
Button.module.scss:
.Button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.clear {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
}

Подскажите, как избавиться от ошибок и перейти на import cls?

Визуально вы по разному делаете импорт, в одном месте * as cls во втором cls. Так же не показан участок кода, где происходит ошибка. Сама ошибка Cannot read properties of undefined означает, что вы пытаетесь из undefined взять ключ Button.

@SwaD Добавил код из файла Button.tsx в вопрос. Этот импорт я делаю в одном и том же месте. В Button.tsx. Просто, из-за разного импорта, разные ошибки. В одном случае в тесте, в другом случае в приложении.

и пример ./Button.module.scss тоже нужно Добавить

Конструкция вида import cls from './Button.module.scss' будет работать, если у вас есть дефолтный экспорт. Если такого нет, попробуйте использовать import * as cls from './Button.module.scss'

@SwaD, scss - это файл стилей и импортом его занимается лоадер вебпака

@Grundy, добавил

@SwaD, пробовал заменить в global.d.ts экспорт на export default classNames; - не помогло.
Я написал выше, что при такой записи import * as cls from в приложении нет ошибок, но появляется ошибка в тесте. Поэтому хочется отказаться от этой записи и перейти на первый вариант

Проблема оказалась в версии css-loader.
Версия 7.1.2 выдавала ошибку.
После установки версии 6.6.0 ошибка пропала.
